# Groovy - Calculate if certain minutes are elapsed from the current time

Tags: java, datetime, grails, groovy, elapsedtime

I have a groovy script which runs as a service after every 1 minute. The groovy service runs properly.

In this groovy script we have to date-time fields named- **Shutdown Start Time** and **Shutdown End Time** for a ticket. I want to trigger an email after ever 120 mins (2hrs) of the **Shutdown Start Time** until current time is less than **Shutdown End Time**, which is the future date.

Below is the groovy script to get the elapsed minutes between the current time and the Shutdown Time. However, I am not able to figure out how can I check if the the elapsed minutes are in multiples 120 mins.

```
import java.util.Date
import groovy.time.*
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit 
import java.util.Calendar

CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = componentManager.getCustomFieldManager()
CustomField downTimeStart = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Shutdown Start Time")
CustomField downTimeEnd = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Shutdown End Time")

Date downTimeStartCFDate = (Date)issue.getCustomFieldValue(downTimeStart) //Get the Shutdown Start Time
Date downTimeEndCFDate = (Date)issue.getCustomFieldValue(downTimeEnd) //Get the Shutdown End Time

//Get elapsed time between the current time and the Shutdown Start Time     
TimeDuration startDuration = TimeCategory.minus(new Date(), downTimeStartCFDate)
long downtimeStartElapsedMinutes =TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(startDuration.toMilliseconds())

//Get elapsed time between the current time and the Shutdown End Time                   
TimeDuration endDuration = TimeCategory.minus(downTimeEndCFDate, downTimeStartCFDate)
long downtimeEndRemaniningMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(endDuration.toMilliseconds())

//This sample 'if' condition checks if 12 minutes are elapsed. 
if(downtimeStartElapsedMinutes % 3 == 0 && downtimeStartElapsedMinutes % 4 == 0)
{
  //Send an email
}
```

The above groovy script is implemented as a service which runs after every minute. In this groovy script I just need to check if the elapsed time between the current time and the **Shutdown Start Time** is 120 mins (2 hrs) until the future **Shutdown End Time** date arrives.

That is, let's say -

**Downtime Start - 2014-10-06 23:00:00.0**
**Downtime End - 2014-10-07 18:51:00.0**

Then,
The groovy service which will run after every 1 minute should trigger emails after every 2 hrs from the date of Downtime Start till the Downtime End datetime arrives -

**Downtime Start - 2014-10-06 23:00:00.0**

1st Email Sent - 2014-10-07 01:00:00.0

2nd Email Sent - 2014-10-07 03:00:00.0

3rd Email Sent - 2014-10-07 05:00:00.0

4th Email Sent - 2014-10-07 07:00:00.0

5th Email Sent - 2014-10-07 09:00:00.0

6th Email Sent - 2014-10-07 11:00:00.0

7th Email Sent - 2014-10-07 13:00:00.0

8th Email Sent - 2014-10-07 15:00:00.0

9th Email Sent - 2014-10-07 17:00:00.0

**Downtime End - 2014-10-07 18:51:00.0**

It would be of very help if anyone can share inputs on this as I am not familiar with the groovy scripting.

Comment: so you want to send email every 2 hrs until the end time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isn't it way too complicated?

```
final long TWO_HOURS_MILIS = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000l

Date downTimeStartCFDate = (Date)issue.getCustomFieldValue(downTimeStart)
Date downTimeEndCFDate = (Date)issue.getCustomFieldValue(downTimeEnd)
long now = System.currentTimeMillis()
long delta = now - downTimeStartCFDate.time

// fire between 1:59 and 2:00
if( delta % TWO_HOURS_MILIS >= TWO_HOURS_MILLIS - 60000 && now < downTimeEndCFDate.time ){
  sendEmail()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @injecteer. But I believe here in the if block the email will be triggered only for the first time when 2 hrs are elapsed after the Downtime Start. This email triggering process needs to be incremental which will send email **after every 2 hrs** from Downtime Start until Downtime End date-time approaches.

Comment: I think your casts to `(Date)` are superfluous.  That cast will happen automatically because the variables have static a static type of `Date`.

Comment: I copied the original :)